# Can't create table in database VB2012

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a table. But when table was saved. I can't found new table in Data Explorer.

Project > Add new item > Service-base Database

[image]

[image]

Comment: what happen if you click the save icon in the first image?

Comment: show dialog in second image

Comment: You haven't saved your table i guess or it may be loacted in anyother location please double check it

Comment: Thank you. I can fix it. So must click update icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Please refer this link also. [Click Here..!!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/fy685z3w.aspx)